# Accelerate spleeter on m1 mac

Tags: macos, monterey, apple-silicon

I'm using spleeter to separate audio into different stems. After many tries I get it working with tensorflow-macos using tensorflow-metal plugin. I assume that it is being run on the GPU.

However, I saw that on spleeter's GitHub page, it states that Nueral Mix Pro uses spleeter in the backend, so I tried it. Neural Mix Pro separated the same audio track much faster (2-3 sec vs 10+ sec), and it seems like it used the neural engine based on output of `powermetrics` (non-zero power consumption of ANE and unchanged CPU and GPU power consumption).

I still want to use spleeter because I hope to train the default model with vocaloid stems to separate vocaloid songs better (which currently does not work at all). Is it possible for tensorflow to use ANE for processing? Is the speed difference solely due to using GPU vs using ANE or is additional optimization/processing needed for this kind of increase in speed?

Comment: Isn't this something which is better raised directly on the GitHub page of the software you are using?

Comment: @nohillside It's about how (and when) to use the neural engine in general, with spleeter just being an example.

Comment: Not even sure this is a user-level decision. But can you edit to ask this more specifically, right now the question seems to focus on spleeter.